# Can't see Image using custom layout

Tags: android

This my custom layout which I'm using to show my custom view with ImageView.But problem which Im facing is can't see image when I run this layout.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlo"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:layout_below="@id/rlo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:gravity="left|top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="   HELP"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="App Name" />
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView 

android:layout_below="@id/popup_window"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/libmap">

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java :
How is it called...

```
final LinearLayout popup = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.popup_window); 
 popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle1);
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
     if (key == 0) {
        key = 1;
      popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else if (key == 1) {
        key = 0;
        popup.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
     } 
} 
});
```

Please help to resolve this probelm.

Comment: can you please post some code ?

Comment: I have updated my question please take look

Comment: And In my activity I'm using component of this layout like this.

Comment: final LinearLayout popup = (LinearLayout)     findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
   popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.handle1);
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (key == 0) {
     key = 1;
     popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    
    } else if (key == 1) {
     key = 0;
     popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     
    }
   }
  });

Comment: Im expecting help from all Android Experts :) on this.

Comment: can you post image how it look like or you wan to show ?

Comment: can you post the screen shot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Everyone but This is not what I expected, If you run this code you will get button on top and if you click on button header part will move from left to right and again right to left on button click.So i dont want to change this behaviour and wants to add Image as well.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for help this is working code I have posted enjoy :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_top_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/handle2"
            android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:text="       HINTS"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15px" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:src="@drawable/help_state2" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:divider="@color/WhiteSmoke"
            android:dividerHeight="4dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/popup_window"
        android:background="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/handle1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/help_state2"
            android:gravity="left|top" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/name" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/location"
             android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:gravity="right|top"
            android:background="@drawable/location" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout  
        android:id="@+id/popup_window"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="HELP"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/handle1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Handle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="App Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Harsh but This is not what I expected, If you run this code you will get button on top and if you click on button header part will move from left to right and again right to left on button click.So i dont want to change this behaviour and wants to add Image as well.Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageView` you are using `android:layout_below="@id/popup_window"` which is not valid for `LinearLayout`. You should use either use `RelativeLayout` or do something else.

```
<ImageView 
android:layout_below="@id/popup_window" <!-- invalid property for LinearLayout--!>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/libmap">
```